# excluded_subdomains doesn't seems to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apartment-gem

## config/initializers/apartment/subdomain_exclusions.rb

`Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']`

Above doesn't seems to be working. I'm using rails 5.0.2.

in apartment.rb I have this

```
Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www', 'admin']
Rails.application.config.middleware.use'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain'
```

To test on local i have added hosts

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com admin.example.com
```

on www.example.com I got error `Apartment::TenantNotFound`
What I'm missing here.

Comment: Define *not working*. What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead? Is there a error message? What does it day?

Comment: The documentation adds the middleware in the `config/application.rb` file and uses a constant not a string. Maybe one of those two things is creating an issue? https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switch-on-subdomain. Is your `apartment.rb` in `config/initializers`?

Comment: @spickermann By not working I meant that when I hit url www.example.com I should try to find any tenant rather it should use public database.

Comment: @Puhlze `apartment.rb` is in `config/initializers`.  constant or string it does worked for me.